# Unable to boot to Ubuntu after a restart

Tags: grub2

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8 for almost a year and a half. And one day when I restarted to switch to Ubuntu I wasn't able to see the grub options for dual boot and when I tried to go to boot options and chose Ubuntu it says "Selected boot device failed". What could be the reason for this and will I be able to recover the data stored on my Ubuntu partition. Please Help

[image: Look at this image for the disk partition]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the partition layout from the Disk Management program included with Windows.

Comment: @user68186 Is it really only a grub problem because if I boot ubuntu from BIOS boot options it shows SELECTED BOOT DEVICE FAILED while windows option boots perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some surfing around  I got the answer. 
I made a bootable Ubuntu pen drive and chose the option to try Ubuntu.
Then followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to run boot-repair and I was able to boot to Ubuntu again